# Homeo- and diffeomorphism groups of oriented surfaces

Tags: reference-request, surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry

I'm interested in the structure of homeo- and diffeomorphism groups of oriented surfaces, especially in hyperbolic case. For example, does the homeomorphism group retracts on the diffeomorphism group (fixing smooth structure) or the isometry group (fixing a Riemann metric with constant curvature)?

So could you give me references on the articles, or better, books about these topics? I'd also like to read the motivations and standard examples of topologies on these groups, isotopies of different structures and other technical things.

Comment: The isometry group is much smaller; it's finite by Hurwitz's theorem. The diffeomorphism and homeomorphism groups are, I think, both homotopy equivalent to the mapping class group. (This is all in the hyperbolic case.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: It is a theorem of M.-E. Hamstrom, Ill. J. Math 1966, that if $S$ is a compact oriented surface of genus $\ge 2$ then each component of the homeomorphism group is contractible. I have not found a reference for the diffeomorphism group.